# Rxjs operator withLatestFrom does not work as expected

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an observable `userInput$` that returns streams of data every N seconds when user typing to to input. I want to receive the latest input and pass that as parameter to the function `service.search(x)` that will return another observable with the list of data.

```
this.userInput$
  .pipe(withLatestFrom(x => this.service.search(x)))
  .subscribe(x => {
    //do not receiving any data here
  });
```

Any why my code does not work?

My `userInput$` return a `string` my `this.service.search(x)` returns an array - that is what I want to get in result.

UPDATE:

```
const example = this.userInput$
  .pipe(withLatestFrom(x => this.service.search(x)),
  map(([userInput, searchOutput ]) => { // error here
    return {query: userInput, result: searchOutput};
  })
);
```

`[userInput, searchOutput]` - getting an error `[ts] Type 'Observable<GetSearch[]>' is not an array type. [2461]`

Just for test changed `this.service.search(x)` to `of(x)`

```
const example = this.userInput$
  .pipe(withLatestFrom(x => of(x)),
  map(([userInput, searchOutput ]) => { // error here
    return {query: userInput, result: searchOutput};
  })
);
```

the `map` returning an error `[ts] Type 'Observable<any>' is not an array type. [2461]`

Comment: what does userInput$ return? & what does search(x) return? what do you expect in subscribe?

Answer (score 1):

Two observations:

First, you're not actually piping to `map` unless your code sample is a typo, it should like this instead:

```
const example = this.userInput$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(x => this.service.search(x)),
  map(([userInput, searchOutput ]) => {
    return {query: userInput, result: searchOutput};
  })
);
```

Second, `withLatestFrom` is intended to provide the latest value(s) emitted by the supplied observable(s) not receive and respond to changes from an upstream observable which is more akin to `switchMap`. Consider this instead:

```
const example = this.userInput$.pipe(
  switchMap(x => this.service.search(x).pipe(
    map(searchOutput => {
      return {query: x, result: searchOutput};
    })
  )),
);
```

Please note that this assumes `this.service.search` returns an `Observable` response. If it does not, you would need to wrap with `from` or `of` per the actual return type of `search`.

Answer (score 0):

You have piped the output from userInput$ to withLatestFrom but subscribe still doesn't know what to provide as the output. Here you need to map your output.

Try this.

```
const example = this.userInput$
  .pipe(withLatestFrom(x => this.service.search(x)),
  map(([userInput, searchOutput ]) => {
    return {query: userInput, result: searchOutput};
  })
);
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val.result));
```

Comment: in map function `[userInput, searchOutput ]` - getting an error `[ts] Type 'Observable<GetSearch[]>' is not an array type. [2461]`. See the updated question.

Comment: can you share how the userInput observable is transmitting values?

Comment: Any resolution to this, I am getting a similar issue trying to implement `withLatestFrom` and `map`. ` Type 'Observable<GlobalEntityState>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.`